# How to save AndroidManifest.xml file Unity?

Tags: c#, android-studio, unity-game-engine, admob

So i'm trying to integrate Admob to Unity and I have tried everything literally everything to do so but nothings seems to work.

But I have noticed one thing that could be the problem..

Everytime I build the game the AndroidManifest.xml is changed back to its default values I mean the problem as you can see down below is with the App ID and the way to add the add is by adding this:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID"/>
```

so I add that meta-data with my AppID of course and then build the game and everytime I go and check the AndroidManifest.xml file I can't find that meta-data!

**So my question is: How to make AndroidManifest.xml actually save these changes?**

```
2019-07-30 01:28:10.168 26563-26563/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test.test, PID: 26563
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to find your app ID.                                                       *
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6655)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6548)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:267)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1963)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7470)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to assign an id, but you have to add these statements to the AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true"/>
```

under Assets->Plugins -> Android -> GoogleMobileAdsPlugin -> AndroidManifest.Xml inside

```
<application>
</application>
```

appliction tag and then save the AndroidManifest.

It worked for me.

Comment: i will give that a try